css mui styled Сделать чтобы при наведении на любой из блоков Box менялся background на обоих сразу
Есть два Box
        <>
                    <Box width='100px' height='100px'>
                        Box1
                    </Box>
                    <Box width='100px' height='100px'>
                        Box2
                    </Box>
                </>

Нужно сделать так чтобы при наведении на любой из них, у них обоих менялся background?
Можно это как-то сделать на styled ?
я нашел примеры как делают на обычном css,
Как при наведении на один элемент менять стили другого элемента?
а мне нужно на styled components mui

Пробовали через события при наведении заменить стили компонента?

да это логично, но у меня при наведении нужно выделать два разных компонента, причем это получается сделать через div                         onMouseOut={() => setHoveredSequence('')}
onMouseOver={() => setHoveredSequence(query_sequence.name)} но как сделать это через Box у Box нет таких методов как onMouseOver, по итогу я обернул свои боксы в дивы, добавил такие методы и по наведению записываю в стейт что нужно выделить, делаю это в двух разных компонентах, ну и соответственно потом у боксов меняю background, как бы это сделать через Box, может кто знает?
